# Linux- rename all files in a folder

Tags: linux, unix

I have 1000 .mp4 files in a folder in linux and the name of those files are like this:

```
filename_mywebsite.com_.mp4
```

I need to rename all files with one command

so how i can change

```
 _mywebsite.com_   to   _mywebsite2.com_
```

in all files

so all my files will be

filename_mywebsite2.com_.mp4

Comment: there is a [similar question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122605/how-do-i-copy-multiple-files-by-wildcard) on the linux stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming it as:

```
rename 's/.com_/2.com_/' filename_mywebsite.com_.mp4
```

Comment: @Arlinda You might need `apt-get install rename` or equivalent, but it's always been on every system I've used. Or do you get some other error?

Comment: That's not how rename(1) is invoked. It would be `rename .com_ 2.com_ *.mp4`

Answer (score 0):

run below rename command in local directory.

```
rename 's/mywebsite/mywebsite2/' *.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

A piece of code to rename all the files with the same prefix and appends incremental value

```
declare -i x=1
for f in $(find -type f); do 
  mv -v $f ${f%/*}/change_me_$x ;
  x=$x+1;
done
```